# Using variables from the model in the controller - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm playing around with CodeIgniter for a bit. Right now I'm trying to build a "page overview" page. I got another page where i can create pages, and i want to display those pages in an overview.

Right now i my model i got the following:

```
public function page_list(){
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');

    if ($query){
        $pageListing = "<table class='table table-striped'>";
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $pageListing .= "<tr>";
            $pageListing .= "<td>".$row->title."</td>";
            $pageListing .= "<td>".$row->category."</td>";
            $pageListing .= "<td>".$row->date."</td>";
            $pageListing .= "<td><a href='delete_page/".$row->id."'>delete</a></td>";
            $pageListing .= "<td><a href='edit_page/".$row->id."'>edit</a></td>";
            $pageListing .= "</tr>";
        }
        $pageListing .= "</table>";
    } else {

        $pageListing = "There are no pages to display";
    }
}
```

I know it's not the best way of doing it. I'm obviously writing html code that belongs in the view in a model. Right now i don't bother about that. I'm just trying to figure out how to use the variable `$pageListing` in my controller, and from there load in into a view.

I tried using the variable in the following way:

```
public function displayPages {
    $this->load->model('model_pages');
    $this->model_pages->page_list();
    echo $this->model_pages->pageListing;
}
```

When i can do this successfully i can use `$pageListing` in my view.

Right now i get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Main::$pageListing
Filename: core/Model.php
Line Number: 51
```

As i said before, i know this is not the best practice, to code html in the model, and echo it from the controller. This is pure for experimenting, and I'm just curious how i can make this work. Since i will have to work with other variable from the model in the future, and that will work the exact sameway, except they won't contain whole html codes.

Comment: Another way to think about this -- in your model if there are no results - return false. then in your controller if $this->model_pages->page_list(); returns false -> show a no results view page. That way the "controller" is "controlling" what view is being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the `$pageListing` from the model back to the controller. Add this line at the end of your model function:

```
return $pageListing;
```

**Edit:**

```
public function displayPages {
    $this->load->model('model_pages');
    echo $this->model_pages->page_list();
    //echo $this->model_pages->pageListing;
}
```

OR

```
public function displayPages {
    $this->load->model('model_pages');
    $data['pageList'] = $this->model_pages->page_list(); //assign to a variable
    $this->load->view('pagelist', $data);  //is a file pagelist.php in your views folder
```

}

Now if you do the second way(correct way) in your pagelist.php, you will get the variable `$pageList`. Then just `echo $pageList` in your viewfile.

Comment: This does not fix the problem. I still get the same error message that the variable is undefined.

Comment: The second option worked! Thanks a lot. This really helped me in understanding! Thxx